# How to tail server.log and grep multiple text combination?

Tags: grep, tail

The server log is too large, I would like to grep the logs which has "/API/login" and "/API/init" from the server log.

I'm able to use:

```
tail -f /server.log | grep -i "/API/login"
```

to capture those with "/API/Login"

How to add in another condition to include "/API/init" as well?

I've tried this but couldnt work:

```
tail -f /server.log | grep -i "/API/login" || grep -i "/API/init"
```

Another thing is how to output this filtered logs to a text file?

Thank you.

Comment: You can pass multiple expressions to grep using `-e`, or use a regex to grep for `/API/(init|login)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `-e` flag

From the man page:

> -e pattern,  [...]
> This option is most useful when multiple
> -e options are used to specify multiple patterns, or when a pattern begins with a dash (`-').

```
 tail -f /server.log | grep -ei "/API/login" -ei "/API/init"
```